# Getting error in Synapse notebook while running show spark dataframe in dedicated SQL pool

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

Since yesterday I've been facing up with a strange exception when I run
df.show() or any other spark action operation.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4035.showString.
: com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.SQLAnalyticsConnectorException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT statement failed as the path name 'abfss://******@**********.dfs.core.windows.net/container/folder/subfolder/SQLAnalyticsConnectorStaging/application_1377007503111_0003/fdfs26LUOq2d98e1bbc05c4795ba28ecbb4192fbfsadfd.tbl' could not be used for export. Please ensure that the specified path is a directory which exists or can be created, and that files can be created in that directory.
    at com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.ItemsScanBuilder$PlanInputPartitionsUtilities$.extractDataAndGetLocation(ItemsScanBuilder.scala:184)
    at com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.ItemsScanBuilder.build(ItemsScanBuilder.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.PushDownUtils$.pruneColumns(PushDownUtils.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2ScanRelationPushDown$$anonfun$pruneColumns$1.applyOrElse(V2ScanRelationPushDown.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2ScanRelationPushDown$$anonfun$pruneColumns$1.applyOrElse(V2ScanRelationPushDown.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:589)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1235)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.OrderPreservingUnaryNode.mapChildren(LogicalPlan.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:589)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:589)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1235)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.GlobalLimit.mapChildren(basicLogicalOperators.scala:1348)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:589)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:528)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2ScanRelationPushDown$.pruneColumns(V2ScanRelationPushDown.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2ScanRelationPushDown$.$anonfun$apply$6(V2ScanRelationPushDown.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2ScanRelationPushDown$.$anonfun$apply$7(V2ScanRelationPushDown.scala:50)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2ScanRelationPushDown$.apply(V2ScanRelationPushDown.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2ScanRelationPushDown$.apply(V2ScanRelationPushDown.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:211)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:200)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$optimizedPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$2(QueryExecution.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:626)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertOptimized(QueryExecution.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertSparkPlanned(QueryExecution.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.simpleString(QueryExecution.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$explainString(QueryExecution.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.explainStringLocal(QueryExecution.scala:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3869)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2876)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:3097)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:340)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

And here are some additional details:

1. The code ran perfectly 2 days ago.
2. Since yesterday I've been struggling with the exception
3. The code executes without any obstacles in my counterpart's session. But it doesn't (spitting out the exception) in my own one.
4. The dataframe represents spark.read.synapsesql()
5. No grants were not revoked from my account as our devops engineer claims.

Did anyone face with that? How the issue was resolved?
Thank you.

1. Within the struggle I double checked the query in SSMS. It worked.
2. I ran other notebooks where spark.read.synapsesql was used. There were the same exceptions.
3. I am allowed to create/write/remove objects in the ADLS storage account.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the issue fortunately. I removed dynamically created [External tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPWfM.png), [External data sources and file formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aI8C.png) and the notebook ran successfully.